# Copy range based on criteria then dynamically create a new worksheet containing it

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with values, what I want is with each unique value in column F to make a sheet named that, and copy all those rows to the new sheet.

this code looks close, but i need it to make a new sheet with each criteria (individuals)

```
Sub NewSheetData()

    With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

Dim Rng As Range, rCell As Range

 Set Rng = Range([A1], Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each rCell In Range("MyTable")
On Error Resume Next
    With Rng
        .AutoFilter , field:=1, Criteria1:=rCell.Value
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .AutoFilter
    End With
On Error GoTo 0
Next rCell

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3 procedures bellow, in a separate module, will create and populate new sheets with unique values in column F, on the main sheet

---

> This uses dictionaries and **late binding is slow**: <strike>CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")</strike>
>
> **Early binding is fast**: VBA Editor -> **Tools** -> **References** -> Add **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Const X As String = vbNullString

Public Sub GetUniques()
    Const MAIN_COL As Long = 6    'F            '<-------------------- update column number
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr As Variant, r As Long, rng As Range, d As Dictionary
    Dim val As Variant, wsNew As Worksheet, lr As Long, lc As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  '<-------------------- update sheet name
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, MAIN_COL).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, MAIN_COL), ws.Cells(lr, MAIN_COL))
    arr = rng:  Set d = New Dictionary
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Len(arr(r, 1)) > 0 Then
            val = CleanWsName(CStr(arr(r, 1)))
            If Not d.Exists(val) Then d.Add val, X
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False:     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each val In d
        Set wsNew = MakeWS(val)
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & val
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lr, lc)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        With wsNew.Cells(1, 1)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wsNew.Activate: .Cells(1, 1).Select
        End With
    Next
    ws.Activate:    ws.Cells(1, 1).Copy:    rng.AutoFilter
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True:      Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function CleanWsName(ByVal wsName As String) As String
    Const x = vbNullString

    wsName = Trim$(wsName)    'Trim, then remove [ ] / \ < > : * ? | "
    wsName = Replace(Replace(Replace(wsName, "[", x), "]", x), " ", x)
    wsName = Replace(Replace(Replace(wsName, "/", x), "\", x), ":", x)
    wsName = Replace(Replace(Replace(wsName, "<", x), ">", x), "*", x)
    wsName = Replace(Replace(Replace(wsName, "?", x), "|", x), Chr(34), x)

    If Len(wsName) = 0 Then wsName = "DT " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh.mm.ss")
    CleanWsName = Left$(wsName, 31)         'Resize to max len of 31
End Function

Public Function MakeWS(ByVal wsName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet, result As Boolean, activeWS As Worksheet, id As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        If .Worksheets.Count = 1 And .Worksheets(1).Name = wsName Then Exit Function
        id = IIf(ActiveSheet.Index = 1, ActiveSheet.Index + 1, ActiveSheet.Index - 1)
        Set activeWS = ActiveSheet
        If activeWS.Name = wsName Then Set activeWS = .Worksheets(id)
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            If ws.Name = wsName Then
                ws.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Set ws = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count))
    End With
    ws.Name = wsName
    activeWS.Activate
    Set MakeWS = ws
End Function
```

---

Hope this helps

Comment: hey there, thank you this creates the sheets based on the column I selected, however it doesnt populate over the unique rows from the main sheet. also I had to adjust the code a bit to change the dictionary to an object as a Dim and then CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"). (im using 2016).

Comment: hey there, thank you i realised some of my values were > 31 so it wasnt matching. I will make a filter to fix them up so its less then 31.. also I had to adjust the code a bit to change the dictionary to an object as a Dim and then CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"). (im using 2016).So this works a treat. Paul, thank you for this

Comment: Great ! I'm glad you have it figured out. I also added a note about adding an early binding to Microsoft Scripting Runtime (it's a bit faster to do it like that)

Answer (score 0):

How about this? If you don't need the filtered list for anything else, you could also read it into a variable and pick the unique items to another variable and the create the sheets based on the latter one?

```
Sub NewSheets()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Dim vList()
    Dim vUniqueList()
    Dim vUniqueCount As Integer
    Dim vIsUnique As Boolean

    vList = Range([A1], Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    ReDim vUniqueList(1 To UBound(vList, 1))
    vUniqueCount = 0

    For n = 1 To UBound(vList, 1)
        vIsUnique = True
        For m = 1 To UBound(vList, 1)
            If vUniqueList(m) = vList(n, 1) Then
                vIsUnique = False
            End If
        Next m
        If vIsUnique Then
            vUniqueCount = vUniqueCount + 1
            vUniqueList(vUniqueCount) = vList(n, 1)
        End If
    Next n

    For n = 1 To vUniqueCount
        With Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
            .Name = vUniqueList(n)
        End With
    Next n

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```